# Работа с классами Delphi

Tags: delphi, классы

Это кусок кода для работы с классами. Т.е. создал класс Tso и описал процедуры.

> `[DCC Error] Unit2.pas(68): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: 'Tso.Eat'`

Проблема в том, что я не описал процедуру, но её же пока не нужно описывать?

```
unit Unit2;
interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComCtrls;

type
  Ts = record
    Eat: string[20];
    Name: string[30];
    Year: string[5];
  end;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    GroupBox1: TGroupBox;
    Label1: TLabel;
    .....
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

type
  TSo = class
    procedure Eat;
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;
  my: TSo;
  f: file of Ts;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object Pascal не поддерживает `inline описание` методов класса и записей( сишных структур ), как это может C|C++. Так, что в классах и записях идет одно лишь описание без реализации. Сама реализация происходит уже вне класса или записи. Поэтому, реализовывайте код функций и процедур вот так:

```
procedure Tso.Eat();
begin
// some actions...
end;
```

И, кстати, реализация всех описанных методов обязательна, как и в C`ях.

Comment: Только на момент компиляции в сях имплементация не нужна если метод не используеться, а в паскале нужна, т.к. он сразу и линкует.

Answer (score 1):

Почему это ещё не надо? Это не си, это Object Pascal

Добавьте в секцию implementation заглушку:

```
procedure Tso.Eat;
begin
end;
```

Answer (score -3):

А про virtual;abstract; никто не знает чтоли?

```
TSo=class
  procedure Eat;virtual;abstract;
end;
```

и нечего не надо в  implementation  добавлять.

Comment: т.е. вы предлагаете использовать директивы "virtual;abstract;", как простую заглушку?  
следующий вопрос:  
вы знаете для чего они нужны?

Comment: А с чего все решили что Автору вопроса нужна заглушка?
Вопрос звучал так
"Проблема в том, что я не описал процедуру, но её же пока не нужно описывать?"
И вполне возможно что описыватся процедура будет в какомто потомке.
Или сперва человеку нужно давать неверное направление чтоб потом гордо сказать
"ООП учить надо".

Comment: я к тому, что если вы даете подобные ответы, то объясняйте квестгиверу, что это и с чем это едят.  

PS. автор не сказал, что будет лепить потомков из этого класса  
PPS. у автора могло сложиться ложное впечатление, что вы дали ему пример заглушки

Comment: Vahan Av, вы действительно знаете ли значение виртуальных абстрактыных методов класса? =)

Comment: ну если я тут теперь чтото напишу всегда можно будет сказать что прогуглил и скопировал )). Если вам это дествительно интересно всегда готов показать проекты над которыми я работаю.

Ну думаю здесь на совсем подходяшее место. 
Ну Если чтото серезное есть и это зависит от глубины моих знаний делфи можете на маил написать)).

Comment: @Vahan Av, вы о чем? =)

Comment: <p><a href="/users/5040/asen">Asen</a>

Ну вы уже не в первый раз задаетесь вопросом о глубине моих знаний.

Comment: @Vahan Av, правда не понимаю о чем вы. По мне так, я вас первый раз увидел сегодня =)

Comment: Ну значит вы еще очень невнимательны молодой человек.

Comment: я не ставил вопрос о глубине ваших знаний. я:  
1. усомнился в уместности вашего ответа  
2. намекнул, что не плохо бы было давать развернутые ответы